# How to control the return order using D3.js nest() and rollup()

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm having an issue getting a consistent return/order from my data array using D3.js .nest() and .rollup().  When the array is updated with new name or alike name, the correct number account is correct but I can't set a order from the recent name added to the last name that was added.  I get a random order when a new name is added or another like name is added.  Below is an example of what my recent return looks like. The order I'm seeking to achieve is a fixed order (reverse order) displaying from bottom to top; i.e, Field-8, Field-7, Field-6, Field-5...Field-1. I included an example of my code. I hope this request for advice make sense. My return below:

[image]

```
[{
    "num": 65,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 64,
    "value": "Field-8"
}, {
    "num": 63,
    "value": "Field-7"
}, {
    "num": 62,
    "value": "Field-7"
}, {
    "num": 61,
    "value": "Field-8"
}, {
    "num": 60,
    "value": "Field-6"
}, {
    "num": 59,
    "value": "Field-6"
}, {
    "num": 58,
    "value": "Field-7"
}, {
    "num": 57,
    "value": "Field-8"
}, {
    "num": 56,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 55,
    "value": "Field-4"
}, {
    "num": 54,
    "value": "Field-4"
}, {
    "num": 53,
    "value": "Field-4"
}, {
    "num": 52,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 51,
    "value": "Field-3"
}, {
    "num": 50,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 49,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 48,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 47,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 46,
    "value": "Field-4"
}, {
    "num": 45,
    "value": "Field-4"
}, {
    "num": 44,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 43,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 42,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 41,
    "value": "Field-3"
}, {
    "num": 40,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 39,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 38,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 37,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 36,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 35,
    "value": "Field-4"
}, {
    "num": 34,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 33,
    "value": "Field-3"
}, {
    "num": 32,
    "value": "Field-2"
}, {
    "num": 31,
    "value": "Field-5"
}, {
    "num": 30,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 29,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 28,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 25,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 24,
    "value": "Field-2"
}, {
    "num": 22,
    "value": "Field-2"
}, {
    "num": 21,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 19,
    "value": "Field-4"
}, {
    "num": 17,
    "value": "Field-3"
}, {
    "num": 16,
    "value": "Field-3"
}, {
    "num": 15,
    "value": "Field-1"
}, {
    "num": 11,
    "value": "Field-2"
}, {
    "num": 10,
    "value": "Field-3"
}]



$(function () { 
    var chartData=getListData("ViewsTest");
    var data=[];
    
    for(var i=0;i<chartData.length;i++){
        data.push({"num":chartData[i].ID, "value":chartData[i].Views});
}
    
    initChart(data);
});

function initChart(chartData){
    
data = chartData;
    
var baseCount = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
  .entries(data);

for(var i =1; i<=  baseCount.length; i++){
  $('.vCount').append($('<div/>', { id: 'r' + i, 'class' : 'ansbox'}))
}

var mainDiv = d3.select("body")
  .attr("id", "main");
  
mainDiv.selectAll(".ansbox")
    .data(baseCount)
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", function(d,i) { return  "views"})
    .html(function (d) { return d.key + " : " + d.values ; });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great to see your data. Generally, though, `d3.nest`  will produce keys in the order that it finds them in the data. For example, if the data looks like so:

```
let data = [
  { key: 2, value: "red" },
  { key: 1, value: "yellow" },
  { key: 2, value: "blue" }
]
```

and you nest on `key`, then you're going to get an array like

```
[
  {key: 2, values: ...},
  {key: 1, values: ...}
]
```

Of course, you can always sort the array. Here's an example.

```js
let data = [
  { key: 2, value: "red" },
  { key: 1, value: "yellow" },
  { key: 2, value: "blue" }
];

let nested = d3
  .nest()
  .key((o) => o.key)
  .entries(data)

let div = d3.select('#v5')
div.append('h3').style('margin', '10px').text('Unsorted')


let table = div.append('table')
let head = table.append('tr')
head.append('th').text('Field')
head.append('th').text('Count')
nested.forEach(function(d) {
  let tr = table.append('tr');
  tr.append('td').text(`Field-${d.key}`)
  tr.append('td').text(`${d.values.length}`)
});

div.append('h3').style('margin', '10px').text('Now sort')

nested.sort((a, b) => (a.key < b.key ? -1 : 1))
  
let table2 = div.append('table')
let head2 = table2.append('tr')
head2.append('th').text('Field')
head2.append('th').text('Count')
nested.forEach(function(d) {
  let tr = table2.append('tr');
  tr.append('td').text(`Field-${d.key}`)
  tr.append('td').text(`${d.values.length}`)
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child {
  border-right: solid 1px black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="v5"></div>
```

Having said all that, it's worth pointing at that `d3.nest` has been deprecated and removed in favor of `d3.group` and `d3.rollup`. You might have a look at the [V6 Migration Guide](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide).

Comment: Thank you for you answer and my apologies for not providing the data. I updated my post to include my data.  I'm pulling the data from a SharePoint list. I will update my code with you answer and see if it work for me.  I will report back after.

Comment: Perfect! It worked.  I did a few small tweaks and I got the end results I was seeking to achieve.  I will also review the updated features you mentioned (d3.group and d3.rollup).  Appreciate the guidance.